# How do I sum up a column in a spreadsheet created by using spreadsheet gem by using a formula

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a spreadsheet where i want to sum up a column values. The Spreadsheet::Formula has a very weird documentation. Is Formula supported or should I sum a column by summing up the values of the cells in a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if there is already an existing cell in the worksheet that contains a formula to sum the range you want then you can retrieve the value of that formula (using `Spreadsheet::Formula#value`), otherwise you should just use Ruby code to sum the values from the column required.